# Ajax 2 Requests at once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

im trying to handle 2 multiple requests at once.
1 Request is handling the long PHP script which is finish after 10 minute ( 
im not able to modify it in JS, so its not solution )
2 Request is handling the the return of DB field count from PHP file here is the two files

```
function checkCount(){

$.when($.post('php/getcount.php', function(result){
    $("#message_count").text(result);
   })).then(function(){
      setTimeout(checkCount, 5000);
   });
}
```

Because i cant update the HTML element value in real time in PHP, i have to make this function to update the element everytime 5 seconds. 
the first request is staying on pending, and the getcount.php sent and stayin
on pending too.
Any solution ?

Comment: what do you mean by caching the result?

Comment: If it's a big script, you shouldn't run it too often. Cache the results by saving it in a file or something helps.

Comment: this script should run everytime user clicks, its using some External API and make requests loop'd in the script file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
checkCount();
});

function checkCount() { 
$.post('php/getcount.php', function(result){
$("#message_count").text(result); 
});
setTimeout(checkCount, 5000);    
}
```

Comment: Still not working, i removed the function from the calling function and still both on pending.

Comment: try this one, i have checked it , that works fine to me

Comment: i've tried. but you wrote this without recurisve so i added it. and its still not working..

Comment: Yea, this working good, but dont forget there is another AJAX request of PHP file which ends loading after 10 minutes, this getcount.php shuld be run in background, but all its result is pending, and after the Long script PHP File ends, the getcount.php start to work from Pending to 200 Status code and giving my result.  so its still not working for me.